# iPhone development how to get webview to fill parent view controller

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin-studio

Can anyone please explain how when doing iPhone development I can get a webview component to fill up the width and height of its parent view controller - preferably using the designer?

Using the newer way with storyboards (in Xamarin studio actually). Tried some constraints but these just seem to set a margin etc from the top and bottom, can't find a fillParent option like with Android.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using xib file to create your layout?

Comment: Doesn't it automatically adjust its size to the view when you drag it in?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure about Xamarin ,but in xcode there is a option to pin the sides of a view to parent(constrains) .In your case select the webview and pin its edges to superview,to fill parent.